# Render Vue component tag added by external code

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add simple Vue components to a legacy app. The goal is to be able use some newer technologies without rewriting everything.

Basically I want to be able to put `<tags-input>` element wherever I want and have Vue replace it with a component.

I have instantiated Vue and added some `<tags-input>` elements to the html. I use them as parts of table rows generated originally by ASP WebForms.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import TagsInput from './ClientTags'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
import '../style.css';
Vue.config.productionTip = false

window.VueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    TagsInput
  }
})
```

Initially the `<tags-input>` elements render nicely. The problem is that external legacy JS code adds new rows to the table (WebForms performs some *auto-magic* pagination). After the new rows are added to the DOM, Vue doesn't render `<tags-input>` elements inside them.

So, my goal is:

Whenever a new `<tags-input>` element is added to the DOM (by external JS), it should be rendered by Vue and added to the window.VueApp.

Comment: Vue is data-driven, but it seems you'd like to use Vue by dom-driven. If so, why not use other lib like JQuery? If still like to use Vue, one approach is remount the component with latest data when dom change. so you may use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor the dom change, then remount it(remount will also trigger Mutation).

Comment: @Sphinx I want to take data-driven approach, but the obstacle is large hunk of nasty, legacy code. Inside the components everything is data-driven, however I needed a way plug my components into the existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out (thanks to Sphinx comment). I probably should not be using Vue app at all in my case. Instead I should manually create and mount my components like so:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
var MyComponent = Vue.component('my-component', {
  // camelCase in JavaScript
  props: ['someTitle'],
  template: '<b>[XYZ {{ someTitle }}]</b>  '
})

function dashToCamelCase( myStr ) {
 return myStr.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); });
}

function getAttributes ( node ) {
 var i,
  attributeNodes = node.attributes,
  length = attributeNodes.length,
  attrs = {};

 for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) attrs[dashToCamelCase(attributeNodes[i].name)] = attributeNodes[i].value;
 return attrs;
}

function renderExisting(componentElementName, componentCreator){
 $(componentElementName).each(function(){
  var props = getAttributes(this)
  var component = componentCreator(props)
  component.$mount(this)
 })
}

function renderNew(appElementId, componentElementName, componentCreator){
 var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
   $.each(mutations, function (i, mutation) {
  var addedNodes = $(mutation.addedNodes);
  var selector = componentElementName
  var filteredEls = addedNodes.find(selector).addBack(selector);
  filteredEls.each(function(){
   var props = getAttributes(this)
   var component = componentCreator(props)
   component.$mount(this)
  });
   });
 });

 var canvasElement = $(appElementId)[0];
 obs.observe(canvasElement, {childList: true, subtree: true});
}

function setUpRendering(appElementId, componentElementName, componentCreator){
 renderExisting(componentElementName, componentCreator)
 renderNew(appElementId, componentElementName, componentCreator)
}

$(function(){
 setUpRendering('#myApp', 'my-component', (props) => new MyComponent({propsData: props}))
});
</script>

<script>
function addMyTag(){
 $('#myApp').append( '<my-component some-title="' + (new Date()).getTime() + '"></my-component>' )
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<button onclick='addMyTag()'>Add!</button>

<div id="myApp">
<my-component some-title="aaa"></my-component>
<my-component some-title="bbb"></my-component>
<my-component some-title="ccc"></my-component>
<div>

</body>

</html>
```

I will be happy to accept a better answer.

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice, you will still meet a lot of problems, for example, how you bind data, how you render correctly if external code add some dom nodes into `my-component`